# Call it a day meaning

Tags: idioms

What is the meaning of "**Call it a day/night**".
I have heard people saying "I am calling it a day". I tried to find out the meaning in dictionaries, but could not. Please let me know your answers.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it ask for a definition which you can easily find in the dictionary. I did a google search and found this one: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+a+day

Comment: I see you are a new member. welcome to the forum. Please go through the help section to ask good on-topic questions :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning of the phrase is to quit work and go home; to say that a day's work has been completed. ***I'm tired. Let's call it a day***. The boss was mad because ***Tom called it a day at noon***.

Another example:
"It's past five o'clock so let's call it a day."

The origin of this phrase is explained as below:

The original phrase was "call it half a day", ***first recorded in 1838***, which referred to leaving one's place of employment before the work day was over. The first recorded use of ***call it a day was in 1919***, and of call it a night in 1938.

Comment: Citations for the origin please?

Comment: I would say that _call it a day_ means to go end work, whether or not that day's work has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

Call it a day  also means to retire from  one's profession or one's activity.

We call it a day when we no longer interested in what we are doing and as we feel that we have had enough.

Many players call it a day.

> **Tendulkar called it a day when he felt that he had achieved enough in his cricketing career**.
>
> **The cricket umpires called  it  a day at 4 PM  today due to bad light.**

Here are  two links which help the usage of the idiom.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call-it-a-day

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+a+day